# Tag merge [minidump] - [minidumps]

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

They're the same thing... again :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Number of questions having [minidumps](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/minidumps) are more than those having [minidump](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/minidump) so I've proposed [minidump](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/minidump) to be a synonym for  [minidumps](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/minidumps).

4 votes will approve [the synonym](https://superuser.com/tags/minidumps/synonyms).